# htaccess 2 domains with same parameter

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, subdirectory

Hope you guys can help me out with a probably simple question.

I have 2 domains on 1 sharehost server:
example1.com
example2.com

On the host i have 2 folders in the public_html folder.

```
public_html
-- example1
-- example2
-- htaccess
```

I managed to get both domains to redirect to each folder.

The problem im having is this.
Both pages have a page called "nextpage".
The url looks like this then:

http://www.example1.com/nextpage 
http://www.example2.com/nextpage

but whenever I go to the second url it redirects to the first url.
Hope you can still follow me.

Below is how the htaccess is right now.
I know where the problem is but don't know how to fix it.

```
# pointing for the domain example1.com to folder example1
ReWriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} example1.com
ReWriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !example1/
ReWriteRule ^(.*)$ example1/$1 [L] 

# pointing for the domain example2.com to folder example1
ReWriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} example2.com
ReWriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !example2/
ReWriteRule ^(.*)$ example2/$1 [L]
```

hope it makes sense.
If you require more info let me know.

Comment: **I know where the problem is** ok then please tell us where the problem is?

Comment: Well maybe it's not that hard to figure out.
The first rewritecond is overruling the second one.
I just need to figure out how to be more precise with the rewritecon